# Room with open door and heater : use inside boundary conditions or heat source for PDE?

Tags: thermodynamics, diffusion

I want to model the stationary temperature in a room (=square) that

- has one open door (=side)
- is otherwise perfectly insulated
- is heated through a (circular) heater that is placed somewhere in the middle of the room

The first two bullet points easily translate to zero-Neumann and zero-Dirichlet boundary conditions on the four sides of the square.

For the third bullet point, I can imagine two ways:

1. Create a hole in the square at the location of the heater and use Dirichlet (value=1) conditions for this boundary
2. Use as heat source the indicator function of the heater

Which is the more realistic approach? Or is it a combination?

Answer (score 1):

For all three bullets, you need to use Neumann boundary conditions.

- open door: $Q = k(T_{out door}-T_{room})$
- insulated wall $Q = 0$
- heater boundary (i.e. hole) $Q = P_{heater}$

where $P_{heater}$ is the power of heater. Summation of Q can then be used to calculate the room temperature change,i.e. $$C_p m\frac {dT}{dt} = \sum Q$$

Comment: So $n\cdot\nabla u=Q$? What is $P_{\text{heater}}$ and shouldn't there be a difference in the gradient direction at the heater depending on whether the room is warmer or colder than the heater? Could you provide a reference?

Comment: Take electric heater as an example. There is a consistent voltage and current (or constant power $W=UI$ to the heater . The heater outputs the power to the room. The coil temperature is much higher than room temperature, so room temperature change has negligible effect on the power output or the gradient.

Comment: What if it isn't much higher than the room temperature? Also, forgive my ignorance, but to help me distinguish, when would Dirichlet conditions be appropriate?

Comment: If the heater temperature is not much higher than room temperature, then the heat flux becomes a functin of room temperature. Dirichlet is used for constant wall temperature boundary condition.